# Как написать условие проще или правильнее? Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть код:

```
if (Mtext(stID) = True) or (Mtext(stID) = False) then...
```

как выполнять независимо от результата Mtext = True или False или

```
if (Mtext(stID)) or not(Mtext(stID)) then...
```

есть ли вариант проще?

Comment: Почему бы не убрать проверку вообще?

Comment: это условие `(Mtext(stID) = True) or (Mtext(stID) = False)` всегда истинно (ну если только у Вас случаем не тернарный boolean)

Comment: @KoVadim условие может быть не истинно, еcли результат `Mtext(a: Integer): Variant`

Comment: В любом случае, varian преобразовывается в булен. А оно не может быть котом Шреденгера. Ну кроме одного случая - если функция не чистая (например, там написано что то вида random > 0.5).

Comment: @KoVadim - нет. Обратите внимание, что идет сравнение с булями, а не приведение к булю. Например, Null можно сравнивать, но нельзя приводить. `if NULL = True then .. else if NULL = False then ..
else ..` - отработает 3-я ветка. Я и сам удивился, когда такое в коде увидел, но оно так работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как выполнять независимо от результата Mtext = True или False

Вот так:

```
Mtext(stID);
// if (Mtext(stID) = True) or (Mtext(stID) = False) then...
```

Comment: спасибо. совсем забыл что так можно)